# Make my code more simple

Tags: android

I have an app with 10 list items.All the items onClick have the same layout between them.I have created a new class for every item and using a switch method to move to every activity.Is there any way to make it more simple( and dont have 10 classes but less)?Thanks

```
mylist.add(map);

            map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("name", "aa");
            map.put("address", "aaa");
            map.put("address3", R.drawable.im1);

            mylist.add(map);// i m adding 10 items like this here


            ListAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.row,
                        new String[] {"name", "address","address3"}, new int[] {R.id.TextView1, R.id.TextView2,R.id.imgdiadromes});
            listcafe.setAdapter(mSchedule);



            listcafe.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                      int position, long id) {
                    switch( position )
                    {
                       case 0:    
                        Intent newActivity = new Intent(diadromes.this, monte.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;
                    case 1:    
                        Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(diadromes.this, diadromestherisos.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity1);
                        break;
```

//and i have 8 more cases here

The class mothe.class and the diadromestherisos.class are exactly the same,i m getting the same content view and i m only changing the text and the images(from .setText and.setImageResource).Hope my problem is understandable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're all the same except for the text and image, then you really only need 1 Activity class to handle all 10 cases. What you can do in your switch is populate a Bundle with the ids of the text resource and the drawable resource and pass that into the activity.

So your switch would look like:

```
switch(position){
  case 0: 
      Intent newActivity = new Intent(diadromes.this, YourNewActivity.class);
      newActivity.putExtra("TXT_RESOURCE",R.string.your_text_resource_id);
      newActivity.putExtra("IMG_RESOURCE",R.drawable.your_img_resource_id);
      startActivity(newActivity);
      break;
   case 1:
      //similar to above, but populate with the different resource ids
}
```

then in your YourNewActivity class, you need to read in the extras and use them to populate your UI:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   int textResourceId = extras.getInt("TXT_RESOURCE");
   int imgResourceId = extras.getInt("IMG_RESOURCE");

}
```